# Можно ли убрать с карты Google Maps значки "станции метро", "зоопарки", "остановки"?

Tags: google-maps-api, карты

[image: Значки на карте Google Maps]

Реализована ли в Google Maps такая возможность?

Comment: Это надо исходник страницы менять, т.е. надо определить стили этих api значков и добавить `display: none;`

Comment: Я бы тебе объяснил как, к примеру, в WebView на Android такое реализовать, ну или PHP. А так, я думаю без програмных путей ты это не реализуешь.. Скажи, что тебе лучше, PHP или Java? Я тебе напишу исходный код. Хочешь и так и так напишу.

Comment: Не понимаю причем PHP к google maps api... Лучше PHP

Comment: @L'Esperanza Там не стили, там картинки.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно с использованием [Styled Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorials/styling-the-base-map).

Например, чтобы убрать все автобусные остановки, при создании объекта `google.maps.Map` в options нужно указать:

```
styles: [{
    featureType: 'transit.station.bus',
    elementType: 'all',
    stylers: [
        {
            visibility: 'off'
        }
    ]
]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Тут можно сгенерировать карту выставив все настройки через интерфейс и получить код: https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

Вот код полученный из того генератора для решения Вашей проблемы:

```
[
  {
    "featureType": "poi.attraction",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit.station.bus",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit.station.rail",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```